# How to I create an iframe with the 'srcdoc' attribute having the contents of a HTML file in Python? (not using 'src')

Tags: javascript, python, html, iframe

Here is the function that isn't working:

```py
def combine_html_files(input_file_paths, output_file_path):
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n'
    for i, file_path in enumerate(input_file_paths):
        file = open(file_path, 'r')
        file_data = file.read()
        html += '<h3>{0}</h3>\n<iframe id="{0}" srcdoc="{1}" width="810" height="260" frameborder="0"></iframe>\n'.format(i, file_data)
    html += '</body>\n</html>\n' 
    output_file = open(output_file_path, 'w')
    output_file.write(html)
    output_file.close()
```

It combines a list of HTML files into another HTML file where the contents of the file are in the `srcdoc` attribute.

I have tried doing:

- `file_data = json.dumps(file.read())`
- same as above: `file_data = json.dumps(file.read())` and removing the quotes around the `srcdoc` value `srcdoc={1}`

For reference, this simple static HTML file with just 1 element in `srcdoc` works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>0</h3>
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" id="0" srcdoc="<h3>TEST 0</h3>" width="810" height="260"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
<h3>1</h3>
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" id="1" srcdoc="<h3>TEST 1</h3>" width="810" height="260"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

but once I try a more typical HTML file like this as the value for `srcdoc`:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.337046, 103.892634)
        });

        new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#F0F8FF',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: '#F0F8FF',
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
</body>
</html>
```

...then it fails. The page that loads just shows blank rectangles.
I believe the issue is due to the string's encoding. Using the `json.dumps` method inserted escape characters before quotation marks. However, it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party here but hope this will help someone anyway.

As you mentioned, this is indeed a problem related to string formatting. The characters that are causing trouble are either the trailing \n or ' used when representing your string in Python.

In your case, you can use the html Python library to escape such characters, using the following:

```
clean_html = html.escape(file_data)
```

Which is to be inserted here:

```
...
file_data = file.read()
clean_html = html.escape(file_data)
html += '<h3>{0}</h3>\n<iframe id="{0}" srcdoc="{1}" width="810" height="260" frameborder="0"></iframe>\n'.format(i, clean_html )
...
```

**Please note that you have to change your variable named html in this case, since you are using the html package**.